# How to handle NullPointerException inside for loop in jsp?

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, nullpointerexception

In this code, I have used `Personal personal=new Personal();` object.
But I want to handle null pointer exception here. Please help with me the issue.

```
<%
if(personal!=null) {
    String sNo[] = personal.getsNo().split(",") ;
    String hsnCode[]=personal.getHsnCode().split(",");
    String modelNumber[] = personal.getModelNumber().split(",") ;
    String serialNumber[] = personal.getSerialNumber().split(",") ;
    String labourFree[] = personal.getLabourFree().split(",") ;
    String rate[] = personal.getRate().split(",") ;
    String qty[] = personal.getQuantity().split(",") ;
    String gstSelect[] = personal.getGst().split(",") ;
    String amount[] = personal.getAmount().split(",") ;

 if(modelNumber.length>0){
   for(int i=0;i<modelNumber.length;i++){
%>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;<%=sNo[i] %></td>
        <td>&nbsp;<%=hsnCode[i]%></td>
        <td>&nbsp;<%=modelNumber[i] %></td>
        <td>&nbsp;<%=serialNumber[i] %></td>
        <%-- <td>&nbsp;<%=labourFree[i] %></td> --%>
        <td>&nbsp;<%=rate[i] %></td>
        <td>&nbsp;<%=qty[i] %></td>
        <td>&nbsp;<%=gstSelect[i] %></td>
        <td>&nbsp;<%=amount[i] %></td>
    </tr>
    <%
     }
   }
}
%>
```

> When I'm using this code on local then I did not get any excpetion but got excption only on hosting server

Stacktrace,

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /completeDetail.jsp at line 124

121: <%
122: 
123: if(personal!=null) {
124: String sNo[] = personal.getsNo().split(",") ;
125: String hsnCode[]=personal.getHsnCode().split(",");
126: String modelNumber[] = personal.getModelNumber().split(",") ;
127: String serialNumber[] = personal.getSerialNumber().split(",") ;


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:568)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:470)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.apache.jsp.completeDetail_jsp._jspService(completeDetail_jsp.java:211)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.59 logs.
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to express few concerns in your code before answering this question. As per the first comment `please refrain using java code inside jsp file`.

> Please visit that answer to understand the brief explanation from user BalusC.

Now coming to your question, You've checked only the object `personal` is not null. But inside the object there maybe the chance of getting null values too. So don't split the string before checking whether it's null or not.

```
String[] serialNumber, labourFree;
if(personal.getSerialNumber() != null){
   serialNumber[] = personal.getSerialNumber().split(",") ;
}
if(personal.getLabourFree() != null){
   labourFree[] = personal.getLabourFree().split(",") ;
}
```

Do it for all the fields. It's always better to check null before doing something with that value. Please let me know if this helps.

Cheers..!